# How to upgrade Kernel Version 4.15?

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel

I am in need of some assistance in upgrading from 4.15.0-29.31 generic to kernel version "42.1" fixes:

```
CVE-2018-10323
CVE-2018-10840
CVE-2018-10881
CVE-2018-1092
CVE-2018-1094
CVE-2018-11412
CVE-2018-11506
CVE-2018-12233
CVE-2018-13094
CVE-2018-13405
CVE-2018-13406
CVE-2018-5390
CVE-2018-7755
CVE-2018-8087
```

My issue is I am not able to find this kernel upgrade. I have upgraded my packages using

```
sudo apt-get upgrade linux-generic
```

I have looked [here](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D) and cannot find it.

If someone can point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` should install the latest `4.15.0-70` ubuntu version with all those security updates.

Comment: kernel 42.1??  there is no 4.21 either, so you might want to check what you really need (which I suspect is only a `sudo apt full-upgrade` (assuming you are using an updated software list & current mirror; *akin to what Pilot6 suggested*)

Comment: @guiverc thank you sooo much!! That did the trick!! I rebooted after and now everything is running smooth!! I cannot thank you enough my friend. Now it says, *canonical LIvepatch is enabled. -All available patches applied. 0 packages can be updated. 0 updates are security updates. *Kata containers are now fully integrated in charmed kubernetes 1.16! Yes, charms take the Krazy out of K8s kata Kluster Konstruction.

Comment: @guiverc I guess it could be 4.15.0-42.1. Anyway, your advice seems to have helped, please post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you fully upgrade your supported Ubuntu system, security fixes will be applied.  You can achieve this using

`sudo apt update` to update software lists on your system, followed by (if no errors)

`sudo apt full-upgrade`

From `man apt`

> full-upgrade performs the function of upgrade but will remove
>   currently installed packages if this is needed to upgrade the system
>   as a whole.

ie. `apt upgrade` may be restrained and unable to install all upgrades (which has benefits; it may not required restart of services or reboot) but upgrades may be skipped to achieve this.

Important Security Kernel fixes done by upstream kernel developers to later kernels are backported to supported kernels unless the Ubuntu Security team advise otherwise (*for example a recent nearing EOL LTS kernel didn't have fixes backported to it, instead users were advised to switch to the HWE kernel which did have backported fixes applied if those security patches mattered to them*).